# Convert integer array list into string based in ascii table and compare with string

Tags: java, string, list, compare, ascii

Well, i'm looking for alternative way to do the following thing.

I have a string and a list with integers based on characters from ascii table.
My question is: Can I make an alternative-faster way to compare the strings in order to avoid the following code?

```
public class Main 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        final String word = "Example!";
        final String secondWord = convert(Arrays.asList(69, 120, 97, 109, 112, 108, 101, 33));

        System.out.println(word.equals(secondWord));
    }

    public static String convert(final List<Integer> list) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int num : list)
            sb.append((char) num);

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: what's not good about the code you've shown? are you looking for a more efficient approach or shorter ....?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions about optimizing/reviewing working code belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com, not Stack Overflow. But [read their help first](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure you scope the question adequately.

Comment: Your question is not really answerable in its current form, right now your code is completely static, there is nothing dynamic, so "more efficient" would be to just print "true" or "false". What is supposed to be more general?

Comment: Both, I want to avoid the method which storing each character in the string builder .

Comment: Then dont use a StringBuilder. create an output string and add the char you need to the end of the string with a for loop!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to construct a `List` or a `StringBuilder`.

You can construct a `String` from a `char[]` directly:

```
System.out.println(word.equals(new String (new char[]{69,120,97,109,112,108,101,33})));
```

Comment: well this is exactly what i was looking for. Thank you :)